# How to handle models in partial views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, partial-views

In my parent view, I am declaring the model at the top of the view:

```
@model GEDCPatientPortal.Models.AccountProfileViewModel
```

Then later in that view, I import a partial view:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_SelectPatientScheduleAppointment.cshtml")
```

The problem I'm running into is that this partial view has it's own model declared, because the partial view has a dropdown in it which I want to be strongly typed...

```
@model GEDCPatientPortal.Models.PatientPortalViewModels
....
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.SelectPatient)
```

I understand why I am getting an error, I'm just not sure how to work around it.

> Error: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'GEDCPatientPortal.Models.AccountProfileViewModel', but this
>   dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'GEDCPatientPortal.Models.PatientPortalViewModels'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Controller/View.cshtml", model)
```

to pass the required model into your partial view.

You can make the partial view's model part of the main view's model (e.g. a property `AccountProfileViewModel.PatientPortal`) and pass that into the partial view.

Comment: Ok, so then, in the partial view, if I don't declare a model, how to I keep from getting a compile error when doing something like @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.SelectPatient...)

Comment: You have to declare the model in the partial view, and it has to match the type of the model passed via @Html.Partial(..., model)

Comment: Ok ok, now I understand.  So now I'm just struggling with the syntax of @Html.Partial("~/Views/Controller/View.cshtml", model).  To be exact, what do I put for "model" in the parent view?

Comment: Got it.  @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_SelectPatientScheduleAppointment.cshtml", new GEDCPatientPortal.Models.PatientPortalViewModels())